# func_get_args detect context

Tags: php, function

I have a script where it accepts a varying number of arguments.

I want to use func_get_args to perform operations on said arguments.  If I have one function like this:

```
function Something() {
   foreach(func_get_args($this) as $functions) {
       // Do something
   }

   // Return..
}
```

I want to be able to call this function in, for example, another function to add/save entries.  The add/save function would have arguments 'title', 'description' etc..

I basically want to know if there is a way to detect the context of a function call.  Can I pass something to func_get_args that will let it know that its called in a certain function?  So if I do:

```
function Save($title, $desc) {
$vars = $this->Something();
}
```

I want `$vars` to contain `$title` and `$desc` after modifying them.

Comment: It seems like you are asking for the ability to pass a varying number of arguments between multiple functions.  Well, you can do that in python, but not really in PHP.

Comment: Don't do that! ... your logic will be confused

Comment: @ExplosionPills: you can do that in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.. Not pretty, but it does what I want it to.

```
private function Handle($Function, $Values) {
        $Method = new ReflectionMethod($this, $Function);
        $Result = array();
        $Inc = 0;

        foreach($Method->getParameters() as $Args) {
            $Result[$Args->getName()] = $this->DB->real_escape_string($Values[$Inc]);
            $Inc++;
        }

        return $Result;
}

function Test($a, $b, $c) {
    $Vars = $this->Handle(__FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
    print_r($Vars);
}

print_r(Test(1, 2, 3));

Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 2
    [c] => 3
)
```

I had another way of doing this but the array had to be accessed using `$Vars[0], $Vars[1]`, etc, and I wanted to make it so I could use `$Vars['something'], $Vars['something_else']`.

Comment: I think mine is a lot more elegant, as you don't have to pass any parameters to the function...

Answer (score 0):

Your function has no arguments, so it's not possible to get it with `func_get_args`.

You can get it with inspecting the [backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), and extracting the `args` part.